# does SQL Server handle or lock Transactions between two or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
     Name text,
     Date datetime
)
```

In my application each person will add his/her tasks to this table.
Every night my robot will pick the first task to do, so it calls following Storedprocedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PickTask  
begin
     select top (1) * from Tasks
     delete top (1) from Tasks
end
```

The robot will call `PickTask`  until there is no rows in the `Tasks` table.
My robot works multithread, so I want to know what will happened if two or more thread in my application wants to call `PickTask` ?
at the first I thought the `select` query will execute for both thread, so both threads pick a same row from `Tasks`, after that each one will delete one row, finally the robot do one task for two times and delete one unfinished task!!

I tried to use `TRANC` but I'm not sure, does my application have problem to do Tasks or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change it to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PickTask  

    begin transaction
         select top (1) * from Tasks
         delete top (1) from Tasks
    commit
```

You can be sure that whichever program invokes this first will lock tasks until both steps are done. Then the next program that next invokes picktask will lock tasks exclusively. You probably want to wrap the whole thing in a begin try/begin catch block.

Comment: This does not prevent two threads from running PickTask simultaneously--this simply means that the changes from the DELETE is not executed unless BOTH the SELECT and the DELETE are successful.

Comment: Russ - I think create locks in clients is great because there is less work for SQL Server but when I try the following: 1) Create table tasks, add data. 2) In window 1 I execute the following:   begin transaction
         select top (1) * from Tasks
         delete top (1) from Tasks I get one row back and it waits for a commit. 3) In window 2 I execute  begin transaction
         select top (1) * from Tasks
         delete top (1) from Tasks I get nothing back. Window 2 is waiting for window 1 to commit or rollback. SQL Server does not timeout (by default- you can change lock timeouts).

Comment: Dear @benjaminmoskovits, thank you for your answer, currently I use some thing like your code in my stored procedure, but my question is: is it enough to prevent any mistakes? so are you sure that SQL can handle this LOCK by default with this code? if yes, please show me more references.. thank you so much again.

Comment: Locking in SQL Server is a deep subject. By default SQL Server is (except for cloud databases) in a type of locking called, "Read Committed." I have no idea what your code is doing its entirety so prevent any mistakes is tricky. Please see the following: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10464/sql-server-transaction-isolation-level-read-committed.aspx For a thorough description of locking please see Kalen Delaney's book SQL Server Internals. Please mark, if you can any of the answers as answered.

Comment: thank you @benjaminmoskovits I read that post and found the answer, it' was a complete answer.. thank you so much.. have good times..

Answer (score 0):

You can use application locks in your T-SQL, as noted in this link: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005

You would acquire the lock in your stored procedure, just before the SELECT statement, then release that lock as soon as you delete the row, although you would be better off deleting the row with a WHERE clause that uses the unique key you obtained from that SELECT, since any additions that occurred (though unlikely) between the SELECT and DELETE could be deleted and never selected.

Comment: thank you Russ, but another question, does this solution reduce the performance? is it harmful if I use it many times in my code?